# Pass SharePoint credentials into Ruby on Rails 4.0 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sharepoint, credentials

I am building a web application using RoR 4.0 My entire company logs into our web portal via sharepoint and I am wondering if it is possible to pass sharepoint credentials into a RoR app? In other words, someone can log into sharepoint with their sharepoint credentials, and have those credentials be used to automatically log into my RoR app? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharepoint is probably configured to use Windows integrated authentication, which means either Kerberos (sometimes called SPNEGO) or NTLM. Googling around a bit, it seems like the most common way to integrate this with Rails is to [let the web server handle the authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209477/kerberos-authentication-in-rails) using an add-on module.

I did find a [Devise plugin](https://github.com/atomaka/devise-kerberos-authenticatable) and an [example Rack app](http://www.birds-eye.net/rails/rack-auth-sso-ntlm-kerberos-integrated-authentication.htm) if you really want to do it in Ruby.